# Is there a word for thesaurus-like?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that fits neatly into this sentence?

> My, his lexicon is so large he is practically **thesaurus-like**

My instinct is thesaurean or thesuarian but neither seem to exist.

Comment: What’s wrong with the noun “a thesaurus”? You’re already qualifying it with “practically”.

Comment: ...a walking thesaurus.

Comment: _Thesaurian_ works fine for me, whether it’s made its way into dictionaries or not. _Lexicon_ seems out of place here, though; _vocabulary_ would be better. I can’t think of a concise way to describe the difference between a person’s vocabulary and their lexicon, but it’s something along the lines of the lexicon being the totality of the vocabulary considered with a view to analysing various aspects of it. If you’re just talking about the total number of words the person knows and uses, _vocabulary_ is more natural.

Comment: He's a *thesaurus lex*.

Answer (score 2):

I think, someone's lexicon or vocabulary can be called
'***ENCYCLOPEDIC***'.

According to Collin's Dictionary 
(https://www.dictionary.com/browse/encyclopedic?s=t):

**ENCYCLOPEDIC**

adjective

: pertaining to or of the nature of an encyclopedia; 
relating to all branches of  knowledge.

Comment: I think *knowledge* and *lexicon* are not close enough.